# How does the .clone() method in Three.js save memory?

Tags: javascript, three.js

For the game I'm writing, I'm adding 100,000 trees, each of which is a merged geometry. When I add these from a cloned model using `tree.clone()`, I save tons of memory by doing this, but the game runs at 3 FPS because of the 100k geometries.

In order to get the game up to 60 FPS, I'd need to merge these trees together into a few geometries total. However, when I do this, chrome crashes due to using too much memory.

What's the reason for the extreme memory usage when merging these trees? Is it because I'm undoing the positives of using the `.clone()` function?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to look into instancing, your use case is exactly what the thing is made for.

Alternatively, using `BufferGeometry` instead of regular geometry, should be less memory intensive.

**edit**

What's actually eating your memory is the overhead of the merge operation when it operates on `THREE.Geometry`. The reason for this is that you have to allocate a ton of JS objects, like `Vector3`,`Vector2`, `Face3`, etc. Which then are discarded since the original geometry doesn't exist any more. This stresses everything, even if you didn't experience a crash, you'd experience slow down from garbage collection. The reason buffer geometry works better is because it's using typed arrays. For starters all your floats are floats not doubles, only primitives are being copied around, no object allocation etc etc.

You are eating more memory on the gpu though, since instead of storing one instance of geometry and referring to it in multiple draw calls, you now hold N instances within the same buffer (same data just repeated, and pre-transformed). This is where instancing would help. In summary you have:

**Mesh (Node, Object)**

Describes a 3d object within a "scene graph". Is it a child of some other node, does it have children, where its positioned (Translation), how its rotated, and is it scaled. This is the THREE.Object3D class. Extending from that is THREE.Mesh that references a geometry and a material, along with some other properties.

**Geometry**

Holds the geometry data, *(which is actually referred to as "mesh" in modeling programs)*, file formats etc. hence the ambiguity. In your example that would be a single "tree":

- describing how far away a leaf is from the root or how segmented is the trunk or branches (**vertices**)
- where the leaves or trunk look up textures (**UVS**),
- how it reacts to light (explicit **normals** , optional, but there are actually techniques for rendering foliage with overriden/modified/non-regular normals)

What's important to understand is that this stuff exists in "object (model) space". Let's say that a modeler modeled this, this would mean that he designated the object as "vertical" (the trunk goes up say Z axis, the ground is considered XY) thus giving it the initial **Rotation**, he put the root nicely at 0,0,0 thus giving it the initial **Translation**, by default we can assume that the **Scale** part is 1,1,1.

This tree can now be scattered around a 3d scene, be it in a modeling program or three.js. Let's say we import it into something like Blender. It would come in at the center of the world, at 0,0,0, rotated by 0,0,0, and at its own scale of 1,1,1. We realize that the modeler worked in inches, and our world in meters, so we scale it in all three directions by some constant. Now we realize that the tree is under ground, so we move it up by X units, until it sits on the terrain. But now its going through a house, so we move it sideways, or perhaps in all three directions because the house is on a hill and now it sits where we want it. We now observe that the silhouette is not aesthetically pleasing so we rotate it around the "vertical" axis by N degrees.

Let's observe now what happened. We haven't made a single clone of the tree, we scaled it, moved it around, and rotated it.**We haven't modified the geometry in any way (adding leaves, branches, deleting something, changing uvs), it's still the same tree.** If we say that the geometry is it's own entity, we have a scene graph node that has its TRS set. In context of three.js this is `THREE.Mesh` (inherits from `Object3D`), which has `.rotation`,`.scale`, `position`(translation) and finally `.geometry` (in your case a "tree").

Now lets say that we need a new tree for the forest. This tree is actually going to be the exact copy of the previous tree, but residing at a different place (T), rotated along the Z axis (R), and scaled non-uniformly (S). We only need a new node that has a different TRS, lets call it `tree_02`, it's using the same geometry, lets call it `treeGeometryOption_1`. Since tree geometry one has a defined set of UVS, it also has a corresponding texture. A texture goes into a material, and the material describes the properties, how shiny is the leaf, how dull is the trunk, is it using a normal map, does it have a color overlay, etc.

This means that you can have some sort of `TreeMasterMaterial` that sets these properties, and then have a `treeOptionX_material` corresponding to a geoemetry. Ie. if a leaf looks up the uvs in some range, the texture there should be green, and more shiny, then the range that trunk looks up.

Now lets reiterate the entire process. We imported the initial tree model, and gave it some scale, rotation and position. This is a node, with a geometry attached to it. We then made multiple copies of **that node**, which all refers to the same geometry `TreeOption1`. Since the geometry is the same, all of these clones can have the same material `treeOption1_material` which has it's own set of textures.

This was all a super lengthy explanation of why the clone code looks like this:

```
return 
  new this.constructor( //a new instance of Mesh
    this.geometry ,     //with the sources geometry (reference)
    this.material       //with the sources material (reference)
  ).copy(this)          //utility to copy other properties per class (Points, Mesh...)
```

The other answer is misleading and makes it sound like:

```
return 
  new this.constructor( //a new instance of Mesh
    this.geometry.clone() ,  //this would be devastating for memory
    this.material.clone()    //this is actually sort of common to be done, but it would be done after the clone operation
  ).copy(this)
```

Let's say we want to tint the trees to have different colors, for example 3.

```
var materialOptions = [];

colorOptions.forEach( color =>{

 var mOption = masterTreeMaterial.clone()
 //var mOption = myImportedTreeMesh.material.clone(); //lets say youve loaded the mesh with a material 

 mOption.color.copy( color ); //generate three copies of the material with different color tints

 materialOptions.push( mOption );
});

scatterTrees( myImportedTreeMesh , materialOptions ); 

//where you would have something like
var newTree = myImportedTreeMesh.clone(); //newTree has the same geometry, same material - the master one
newTree.material = someMaterialOption; //assign it a different material

//set the node TRS
newTree.position.copy( somePosition );
newTree.rotation.copy( someRotation );
newTree.scale.copy( someScale );
```

Now what happens is that this generates many many draw calls. For each tree to be drawn, a set of low level instructions need to be sent to set up the uniforms (matrices for TRS ), textures (when trees with different materials are drawn) and this produces overhead. If these are combined and the draw call number is reduced, the overhead is reduced, and webgl can handle transforming many vertices, so a low poly object can be drawn at 60fps thousands of times, but not with thousands of draw calls.

**This is the cause of your 3 fps result.**

Fancy optimizations aside, the brute force way would be to merge multiple trees into a single object. If we combine multiple `THREE.Mesh` nodes into one, we only have room for one TRS. What do we do with the thousands of individual trees scattered over the terrain, what happened to their TRSs? They get baked into geometry.

First of all, each node now requires a clone of the geometry, since the geometry is going to be modified. The first step is multiplying every vertex by the TRS matrix of that node. This is now a tree that does not sit at 0,0,0 and is no longer in inches, but sits somewhere at XYZ relative to the terrain, and is in meters.

After doing this a thousand times, these thousand individual tree geometries need to be merged into one. Easy peasy, it's just making a new geometry, and filling it's vertices, faces, and uvs with these thousand new geometries. You can imagine the overhead thats involved when these numbers are high, JS has its limitations, GC can be slow, and this is a lot of data, because it's 3d.

**This should answer the question from the title.** If we go in reverse, we can say that you had a game that was consuming lots of memory ( by having a model - geometry, of a "forest") but was running at 60fps. You used the clone method to save memory, by breaking the forest apart into individual trees, extracting the TRS at every root, and by using a single tree reference for each node.

Now the gpu holds only a low poly model of a tree, instead of holding a giant model of a forest. Memory saved. Draw call abundance.

FPS RIP.

How do both, reduce the number of draw calls, while rendering a model of a tree, not a forest?

By using a feature called instancing. Webgl allows for a special draw call to be issued. It uses an attribute buffer to set up multiple TRS information at the same time. 10000 nodes would have a buffer of 10000 TRS matrices, this is 16 floats, describing a single triangle with no uvs or normals takes 9, so you can see where this is going. You hold one instance of the tree geometry on the gpu, and instead of setting up thousands of draw calls, you set one with the data for all of them. If the objects are static, the overhead is minimal, since you'd set both buffers at once.

Three.js abstracts this quite nicely with THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry (or something like that).

One tree, many nodes:
T memory
N draw calls

One forest, single node:
T * N memory
1 draw call

One tree, instanced many times:
T + N memory (kind of, but it's mostly just T)
1 draw call

**/edit**

100k is quite a lot, three is probably better at handling this than before, but it used to tank your fps whenever you had more than 65536 vertices. I'm not sure off the top of my head, but it's now addressed by either breaking it up into multiple drawcalls internally, or the fact that webgl can address more than 2^16 vertices.

> I save tons of memory by doing this, but the game runs at 3 FPS because of the 100k geometries.

You still have one geometry, you have 100k "nodes" that all point to the same instance of geometry. It's the overhead of the 100k **draw calls** that is slowing this down.

There are many ways to skin this cat.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'll let you know what my results are when I'm able to test.

Comment: Wow, changing the merged geometry to a BufferGeometry fixed it with ease. I've been working on this problem for at least three days, thank you for the solution.

Comment: If you post some code maybe we could see what else is going on. 

There is a ton of overhead with 'classes' and objects when using `THREE.Geometry`, basically every vertex, every face is an object with a ton of properties, all this needs to be allocated and then deallocated.

Comment: Could also show you an example of using instanced geometry, this would make it even more efficient. You would reduce the amount of drawcalls (could be one for that matter) but you also reduce the memory footprint since you don't have to have one geometry containing M * N verts, but instead have one geometry just containing your M verts (tree) and than instancing the call N times.

Comment: I'll make that as an edit by tomorrow. I hope to help anyone else who has this issue as well.

Comment: What is your FPS with the Buffergeometry?

Comment: added a really long answer to the question in the title,

Answer (score -1):

The problem of memory has nothing to do with the usage or non-usage of the clone() function, which simply makes a separate copy of your object geometry and material.

The memory problem is due to the fact that the program is reaching the memory limit while merging.

The mergin process is an expensive process during setup (loop through all vertices, faces of both objects and create a third combined object). Plus, the merged geometry you are building is getting too large at a certain point to be processed and causes the browser to crash.

Have you tried to split the merged geometry into smaller chunks of 100 objects instead of using 1 merged object to store the 100K trees?

To optimize the code, I would also look at the tree mesh itself and see if you can reduce the number of vertices and faces.

For the usage of that many trees, you might want to consider using tricks and have only a few real mesh for the trees that are close to the camera and for the ones further away use a "waterdown" version (2-3 planes mesh that would need to be merged as well).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I actually have tried making the merges smaller, but even when I set the merge to just 1 tree, it runs out of memory at the same point, around 30,000

Comment: what does 30,000 refer to?

Comment: 30,000 trees, sorry!

Comment: BTW clone should not make a copy of your object geometry. Clone should make a copy of the node (`THREE.Mesh` for example), not copy the geometry, this would be EXTREMELY inefficient.

Comment: For some reason, i am not seeing the Q/A until late... Merging to 1 tree will not make any difference. The solution I am proposing is a best practice long run answer and not a quick fix. try to adjust your mesh performance and object merging count. You are reaching the limits and will not be able to do further until you set bounderies to this creation.

Comment: per the THREE.js docs: .clone ()
Creates a new clone of the Geometry.

This method copies only vertices, faces and uvs. It does not copy any other properties of the geometry.

Comment: clone: function () {

  return new this.constructor( this.geometry, this.material ).copy( this );

 }
looks like a new instance to me...

Comment: new instance of what? i suggest to dig a bit into the WebGLRenderer code to see what's going on there.

Comment: Looks to me like it constructs a new `THREE.Mesh` (could be something else though) with the same instance of geometry. You're either mixing up the docs for `Mesh` and `Geometry` or reading the `Mesh`'s clone function as `return new this.constructor( this.geometry.clone() , this.material /*.clone()*/).copy(this)`. I hope this clarifies things. If you want to draw a 1000 spheres, there is no reason to hold a 1000 instances of the same geometry on the gpu. One sphere would exist in object space, a 1000 nodes would transform it to world space. These nodes contain the TRS matrices needed for this.

Comment: Try doing something like `var mesh1 = new THREE.Mesh( myGeometry ); var mesh2 = mesh1.clone(); console.log( mesh1.geometry === mesh2.geometry); console.log( mesh1.material === mesh2.material);` I hope this clarifies things.

Comment: From what I am deciphering, what is the purpose of merging geometry if cloning geometries is that performant?

Comment: I'm not sure if performance is the only reason why you would merge something. Could be some sort of procedural modeling, for example, you want to arrange a bunch of spheres in some pattern, and then apply noise within the same space to all of them to distort the vertices. And im not sure which part led you to that conclusion, that cloning is performant. The question was quite direct: "How does the .clone() method in Three.js save memory?", i asnwered it by basically saying "it allows you to recycle the same geometry between different draw calls".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133220/discussion-between-pailhead-and-inf1).